# Find and correct the mistakes vs Find the mistakes and correct them

Tags: meaning

Are the following constructions synonymous?

1. Find the mistakes and correct them.
2. Find and correct the mistakes.

And if they are synonymous, which one is more common?

Comment: I would say they were synonymous. You can use Google Ngrams to find out which is more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific instance, yes they mean the same - but don't make the mistake of thinking all 'constructions' like this would mean the same.

It's logical that you can't correct a mistake until you first find it, so you have to do one, and then the other. Other similar constructions may suggest two things that could be done in any order or even at the same time.

- Hold and kiss your loved ones.
- Share and enjoy the cookies.
- Read and watch the Harry Potter series.

In these examples, alternate phrasing *could* suggest that you do one or the other first, that you do them together, separately, or in no particular order!